# how to reduce video file sizes for long term storage

Tags: compression, storage, mkv, video-compression

I have a few gameplay clips with friends, the total size of the clips are around 500 gb it is a little bit big but it became a nice memory with some lost friends so I want to keep it. but its taking so much space. is there a way to compress the files for the purpose of storing them long term? like compress them and when I might want to revisit them in years I can decompress them etc. I want to reduce the size as much as possible even if it means i can't preview the files and it takes long to compress and decompress them.
details:
the file types are .mkv
the size of the videos vary between 25 gb and 1 gb each

Comment: Video is binary data and is hard to compress. You can try running it through video codecs to lower video quality e.g. see https://handbrake.fr. Try experimenting with more aggressive lossy compression and reduce video resolution. You have to lower the quality of the video to gain any significant size reduction. Lossless compression may give you some minor size reduction, but unlikely beyond a couple of percent. Alternatively, you could get a relatively inexpensive external disk and store the original videos there.